# How do I attach source code in VisualStudio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

What is the best/correct way of attaching an external project source code so I can debug it?

I´ve already downloaded the source code of it from CodePlex, so I have all the .cs classes.

I´ve managed to import from a pdb file, but unfortunately, there´s no such file in this project codeplex (SimpleInjector).

After importing the SimpleInjector solution on VS, I could build it and generate the .pdb files, but I wonder whether it is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to step-through debug the binary, then you will need the PDB files. In general, the compiled assembly just doesn't contain the information needed to associate source-code lines with individual IL commands.

The PDB file is a "program database file" which contains lots of useful debugging information; one of those things is the mappings between each compiled IL instruction and the source-code line that generate it. It also keeps a symbol table that lists the names of things that otherwise get compiled out (like local variable names, etc.) The PDB embeds the full path name of each source file, so if your source code is in the same place when you debug as it was when you compiled, the debugger will automatically find it.

If the .pdb file is present but the source code has moved, VS will give you the option to browse to the .cs file. But, if the .pdb file isn't present at all, your options will be rather limited.

The only risk you have is that you are debugging a program that doesn't match your PDB files. Therefore, if you are doing to try to debug the project, you should rebuild, from scratch, in Visual Studio and run *that version* of the binary.

(Debugging without symbols and source loaded into Studio is, of course, possible, but it's a much harder skill to master.)

Comment: Nice. Just to confirm: the way of generating the .pdb file from a project is building it on VS, right?

Comment: Yes. Well, using the .NET build process, whether that's inside VS or via MSBuild or by hand or whatever. The key is that you have to generate the .pdb files during the compilation process, when starting from source code. If you don't produce the .pdb files while compiling, most of the important information you would put in the .pdb files is thrown away and you can't get it back.

Comment: Ok. thanks. IMHO, this approach is a huge drawback comparing to java´s, because there one can attach the source, without the need of building the project itself, as it´s not always simple to build an opensource project.